# symfony2 setting _target_path in request header repeats app_dev.php

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

i am using the following code to generate a redirection after a successful login :

```
$request->request->set('_target_path', $this->router->generate('renew_subscription'));
```

The output url is :

> http://mysite.dev/app_dev.php/app_dev.php/renew_subscription

How can I make sure the app_dev.php is not repeated twice? I feel like str_replace would not be clean enough.

EDIT:

I'm setting this in a login listener. I figured out a login handler was not working because the securitymanager service was not yet corrctly initiated :

```
portfolio_change_and_login_listener:
    class: %portfolio_change_and_login_listener.class%
    arguments: [@security.authorization_checker, @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @session, @security_manager, @router]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: portfolio_change, method: onPortfolioUserChange }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin, priority: 255 }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Where are you setting this?

Comment: I'm setting this in a login listener.

Answer (score 2):

instead of set _target_paath in your controller or service you can set it in form view:

add this field to your login form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="YourRouteName" />
```

"YourRouteName" is name of your route

Comment: not applicable to my case, I am setting this from within a login listener

Answer (score 0):

You should set controller and use a `RedirectResponse`

This is a listener that I use to make sure the next route is the planned next step in a form so users can't jump around.  I check to see if

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterControllerEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class SampleListener
{
    protected $em;
    protected $token_storage;
    private $router;

    function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $token_storage, EntityManager $em, $router)
    {
        $this->token_storage = $token_storage;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
    {

        //some other checks go here

        $route = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get("_route");
        $appStep = $app->getAppStep();


        if ($route != $appStep) {
            //Check to see if the route is going to the planned next stp
            $stepsVisited = explode(",", $app->getVisited());
            if (in_array($route, $stepsVisited)) {
                //if its not going to the next planned step then make sure its a path we visited before.
                return;

            } else {

                $url = $this->router->generate($appStep, array("appId" => $appId));
                $event->setController(function () use ($url) {
                    return new RedirectResponse($url);
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Variable appstep is just a reference to a route name such as place as shown below.

```
/**
 * @Route("/place/{appId}", name="Place")
 */
```

This is what my service looks like.  This is done in yml

```
sample.action_listener:
        class: Bundle\Name\EventListener\AppSecurityListener
        arguments:
            - @security.token_storage
            - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
            - @router
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.controller, method: onKernelController }
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

---

## Edit 1

If you are trying to run redirects after login then you should use a Handler like this.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{

    protected $router;
    protected $security;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {

        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('AnnotationName 4'));
        } elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_B')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('AnnotationName1'));
        }
//        elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN'))
//        {
//            // redirect the user to where they were before the login process begun.
//            $referer_url = $request->headers->get('referer');
//
//            $response = new RedirectResponse($referer_url);
//        }
        else {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('Home'));
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then you need to set a parameter and a service in your services file

```
parameters:
    bundle_name.service.login_success_handler.class: Bundle\Name\Service\LoginSuccessHandler
services:
    bundle_name.service.login_success_handler:
        class:  %bundle_name.service.login_success_handler.class%
        arguments:  [@router, @security.context]
        tags:
            - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

I can't remember where I figure out how to do this but it was after a lot of looking around for examples.  I also have a logout handler that I got from the same place.  I am sure if you search the class name you will find the example somewhere.

Comment: well, I want this redirect after login check and successful authentication. How can I use a controller here if symfony is handling the check part ?

Comment: Are you using fos user bundle or are you just using Symfony?

Comment: I am using fosub, yes

Comment: @SébastienVassaux I updated my answer in the second half.  That should fix your issue I think.

Comment: well, unfortunately, in my case I need a loginListener. I've tried with the login handler, all works fine except I have a dependency on something which does not get updated in time (I have another service taking the tokenstorage as an argument and this token is not yet populated with the user info)

Comment: If you expect anyone to answer your question you are going to need to give all the info.  This is a very simple problem, I am not sure why you are having issues.  Please restate your issue in a clearer manor.   I shouldn't need to dig for info in order to help you.  It sounds like your issue is completely different from the one you stated at the start.  Good luck.

Comment: sorry for that, my question is relative to a redirect in a specific case. yes, you can use a login handler, and that's what I'm doing, but I was looking for a way to make it work from within a login listener

Answer (score 0):

So there is the good way to make a redirect, using a login handler.
See B. Rad answer.

I was looking for a way to make it from within a login listener because when you instantiate the login handler, the token is not yet populated with the user. It is only populated after you call `onAuthenticationSuccess`.
I had a dependency on the user, and I first loaded it with the constructor, it dod not work. Using a setter and calling the depedency from within `onAuthenticationSuccess` was the solution

Anyway, we can also do a redirect from a login listener, using :

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$route = strreplace('app_dev.php', '', $this->router->generate('your_route'))
$request->request->set('_target_path', $route );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Absolute URL's instead Relative ones.

```
$request = $event->getRequest();
$route = $this->router->generate('your_url', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL)
$request->request->set('_target_path', $route);
```

Documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#generating-absolute-urls